# Migrating from Objective-C to Swift : AFNetworking > Alamofire

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, afnetworking, alamofire

I'm trying to migrate a project from Obj-C to Swift but got stuck at this part:

Objective-C:

```
-(void) novoLogin:(NSDictionary *) parametros completionBlock:(void(^)(BOOL sucesso, NSDictionary *retorno)) completion {

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
    [manager GET:url parameters:parametros success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Retorno:\n%@", responseObject);        
        if([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            responseObject = [self dictionaryFromString:responseObject];
        }

        NSString *error = responseObject[@"error"];
        completion(error == nil, responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", operation.responseString);
        completion(NO, @{@"error" : operation.responseString});
    }];
}
```

This is my draft implementation in Swift so far:

```
func doLogin(parameters: NSDictionary, completionHandler: (success: Bool, result: AnyObject?) -> Void) {

    guard let url = apiController.createURLWithComponentsForLogin() else {
      print("Invalid URL!")
      return
    }

    print(url)
    print("doLogin")

    alamofireManager.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: .URL).responseJSON {
      (response) in
      print(response.request)
      print(response.response)
      print(response.data)
      print(response.result.value)

      if let JSON = response.result.value {
        print("JSON result \(JSON)")
      }

      completionHandler(success: true, result: response.result.value)
    }
  }
```

It connects to a PHP webservice, I provide an email and password as parameters and expect to get back a json with {"user_id":"424230"} if succeeds or {"error":"Invalid data"} if fails.

This is the response i get from this test:

```
Optional(<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7a65ff70> { URL: http://<hidden>/ws/index.php?r=webservice/ouvintes/login&email=awebmobile%40test.com&senha=123321 })

Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7a8bf8a0> { URL: http://<hidden>/ws/index.php?r=webservice/ouvintes/login&email=awebmobile%2540test.com&senha=123321 } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 51;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Wed, 20 Apr 2016 12:36:44 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = Apache;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
} })

Optional(<7b226572 726f7222 3a224461 646f7320 496e765c 75303065 316c6964 6f732e22 7d>)

Optional({
    error = "Invalid data";
})
```

I provided the correct email and password... Why cant I get the valid {"id":"123456"} response? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to encode parameters:

```
encodedEmail = emailString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
```

Comment: Hi Melifaro, thanks for taking the time to try and help me.. Yes it does if I do this: `if let JSON = response.result.value {
        print("JSON result \(JSON)")
        print(JSON["error"]!)
      }` However I was supposed to get back an {"id":"123456"} from the server since I'm providing the correct credentials. That's what I can't fidure out...

Comment: Good to know. I have updated the answer per your feedback, so that it's correct now.

Comment: Thanks mate! But that's not my main problem here... I believe it has something to to with parameters encoding, since I am providing email, as awebmobile@test.com, and password as parameters. I think that the '@' is the cause of the problem. I should get back from the server an id:number as a response. In short, my url is not being 'created' correctly after adding the parameters.

Comment: It means that you basically need to encode it. See my suggestion in the answer. Will it work?

Comment: Your solution encodes the email address to 'awebmobile%40.test.com' which is accepted if I try to use it directly on a browser to test the Endpoint, but with the alamofire request it still returns an error:dados invalidos. I can't see why it doe not return the id:123456 as expected...

Comment: I figure it out... I've forgotten to pass the url as NSURLRequest. Thanks for the help!